# Migrate field_collections

Tags: 8, entities, migrations

I'm using Drush and the migrate tools to migrate a Drupal 7 site to Drupal 8. The site uses field_collections which do not migrate. The field_collections page indicates it is probably being deprecated and recommends moving to paragraphs.

I have searched, but all of the custom migrations I have found so far have been flat fielded. I need to figure out a way to convert field_collections to paragraphs, or field_collections to custom entities.

I am generally comfortable with PHP and OOP, but building the entities and/or migrations in a new module have me confused.

How would I proceed to build a migration for a content type that included one or more field_collections, so that the field_collection data would be available in Drupal 8?

Comment: I suggest looking at D7 migrations on Google that move data from Field Collections into Paragraphs. Or just make Paragraphs out of database data. The simplest way is to use say the complete() method found in D7's migrate, creating a new Paragraph/Field Collection entity, set the HostEntityId() and then create ParagraphItem items as needed for the Paragraph. Then save your Paragraph entity. I've done this both with Collections and Paragraphs in D7. I assume the OO steps are similar in D8. Answered elsewhere: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/223718/3279

Comment: I'm looking into trying the data to Paragraphs option. I have had no luck in finding articles on moving data from Field Collections to Paragraphs

Answer (score 1):

There's [a patch in development for the Paragraphs module](https://www.drupal.org/node/2911241) to support migration in Drupal 8. This work is currently undergoing development with recent activity. This might be a good way to get a start on your own work and contribute back to the community.